# Passing value from inside while loop to different class

Tags: java, while-loop, parameter-passing

So let's say I have a main class with a while loop:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int one = 1;

    int counter = 0;

    while (one<100){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        counter += 1;

        Function.Move();

        one++;
    }
```

The counter variable in this loop is counting each second elapsed.

There is a separate class called Function:

```
public class Function {

public static int Move (int result){

result = 1 + counter;
return result;      
}

}
```

So as you can see, inside the Function class's Move method, I want to be able to use the counter variable's new value, which increases with each passing second, to calculate the value of a different variable which will then be returned to the main method.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the value of counter to the Move method inside the Function class to begin with.

Comment: Can you not edit the `Move` method to take two parameters instead of 1?

Comment: Do know what "pass by value" means? So instead of passing `result` (which you're ignoring anyway) pass `counter` instead.

Comment: @Tom Sorry I should have explained that the result variable will come into play later, I ignored it here for simplicity.

Comment: Do `Function.Move(counter);` and inside the move will be `return result + 1;`

Comment: @sam If you need both variables, then pass both.

Comment: why do you return `result` but never use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not shure if i understand what you want to do correctly, depending on where exactly you will need that result variable later i think your coude should look something like this:

```
public class Main {

    int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int one = 1;

        counter = 0;

        while (one<100){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            counter += 1;

            one++;
        }
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}

public class Function {

    public static int move (int result, Main main){

        result = 1 + main.getCounter();      
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use Function.move() anywhere you need it's value in your Programm now.

Beware, though, that you will need your code using the Function.move() to run in a different Thread as the Main Thread. Otherwise it will always return 101 or 1, as the while loop will always be running before or after your call to Function.move(), depending on where you call it (except if you call it from within the while loop, but then you counld just use counter++ without the need to have an extra class)

Comment: This the perfect answer I have been looking for. Thanks buddy